# Emitting an object from many children to a parent in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, null, parent, children, emit

I have a parent and child component in a vue.js app. The child passes an object to the parent in an emit call. Sometimes the child must pass an empty object back to the parent.

The parent has multiple of these child components. When it receives an emit from one of the children containing an empty object, it must update its variable "f" to lose the filter content from that particular child, but still include any content from the other children.
How can I do this? Here is my code, which currently wipes away the entire "f" variable when any of the children pass an empty newFilt object back to the parent. If the other children had emitted newFilt data back to the parent, that data is undesirably no longer present in the parent's "f" variable.

child component:

```
   saveValues() {
      this.recalc();
      // yields something like { city: [ "Chicago", "Rockford" ] }
      let newFilt = null;
      if (this.selectedValues.length > 0) {
        newFilt = {
          [this.columnDef.column_name]: this.selectedValues
        };
      } else {
        newFilt = {};
      }
      this.$emit("filters-changed", newFilt);
    }
```

parent component:

```
methods: {
    onFiltersChanged(newFilter) {
      console.log("in onFiltersChanged... newFilter = " + newFilter);
      this.f = Object.assign(this.f, newFilter);
      console.log(
        "this.f after reassigning new filter: " + JSON.stringify(this.f)
      );
    },
```

Comment: can you create an example on jsfiddle or codepen?

Answer (score 0):

Child components could emit some sort of identificator that will let the parent component know where the emit came from:

Child component:

```js
this.$emit("filters-changed", {name: 'name1', newFilt})
```

Parent component:

```js
onFiltersChanged (payload) {
  let { name, newFilt } = payload 
  ...
}
```

You didn't show us enough code to make a more useful example, but you get the idea, just use the `name` variable in `onFiltersChanged` for finding / filtering objects